# Class to only execute on one Record type on object

Tags: class, record-type

Aim : I would like this utility class to only execute if the record type for flow is "intermittent". Currently there are two Records types. "intermittent" & "pending " and its executing on both record types.

I believe i need to add the following line but uncertain where i need to add it  if(Flow.recordtype.DeveloperName == 'intermittent')

```
public class FlowUtils {
   public static void ValidateCurrencyUpdate(List<Flow__c> flows ) {

      List<Id> opportunityIds = new List<Id>();
      Map<Id, String> oppIdCurrencyCode = new Map<Id, String>();
      for (Flow__c Flow: flows ) {
          opportunityIds.add(Flow.opportunity__c);
      }

      for(Opportunity opp : [Select CurrencyIsoCode from Opportunity where Id in: opportunityIds]) {
        oppIdCurrencyCode.put(opp.Id, opp.CurrencyIsoCode);
      }

      for(Flow__c flow : flows) {
        flow.CurrencyIsoCode = oppIdCurrencyCode.get(flow.opportunity__c);
      }


   }
 }
```

Comment: You can check the below condotion where ever you are calling method of this  class
if(Flow.recordtype.DeveloperName == 'intermittent')

Comment: Hi muzammil. Where abouts does my if statement go though ? That's the problem I  encountering

Comment: From where you are calling this class or where are you using this class?

Answer (score 0):

As @Muzamil Bajaria mentioned, you can check the condition prior to calling this method, or you can add it to this line:

```
Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>(); // Changed to Set to ensure unique Ids
for (Flow__c Flow: flows ) {
    if(Flow.recordtype.DeveloperName == 'intermittent') {
        opportunityIds.add(Flow.opportunity__c);
    }          
}
```

Now your collection of Opportunity Ids are filtered to only include ones associated to Flows of RecordType "intermittent'.

Comment: I think he don't want to execute that class if record type is not  'intermittent'. Which can only be done by giving condition prior to calling your method. We don't know his exact requirement. But I think your answer will also give the expected output.

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria Sorry if there is any confusion around my logic, i would only like to execute that class if the record type is intermittent.

Comment: Then bobforce's answer should work for you

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria i am still encountering an issue, do you think we can take this to a chat ?

Comment: Yeah sure.. Let me know when you are online

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria i am online now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57046/discussion-between-muzammil-bajaria-and-masond3).

Comment: U there @Masond3 ?

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria - apologies i have been on vacation. you want to resume our chat

Comment: so you found any solution ?

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria - You free today to pick up ?

Comment: @Masond3 I am really busy these days. I will let you know when i get free